# How do I get a Christmas tree in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been hearing all about this Christmas tree thing, but I still don't know how to get one. I also heard that today is the last day that you can get one, so I was hoping that I can get one before the Christmas update ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christmas trees are completely random spawn just like any other ground obstacle.  (Only spawning when you aren't playing )

From playing on two different accounts: I noticed that my lower level account spawned 4 Christmas trees while my high level account only spawned 2  during this seasonal theme.   In addition, the lower level account had much more room free to spawn which may have improved my chances for spawning them.

Comment: I thought you had to do something special to get them. Looks like it's based on luck. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is just rarity in the 2013 Christmas update. The lower your Town Hall is, the more will spawn.